# Acesso negado editar arquivos via SFTP no Ubuntu após upload via Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, linux, permissões

Eu tenho um VPS Ubuntu(LAMP) e faço o gerenciamento de arquivos PHP da pasta *www* via SFTP.

Eu utilizo o Wordpress no meu servidor, com ele eu faço upload de pastas e arquivos e também consigo deleta-los. Via Wordpress quando eu faço um novo upload de uma pasta ou arquivo e posteriormente tento deletar ou editar o conteúdo de algum arquivo diretamente via SFTP o servidor me retorna acesso negado. Se eu enviar o arquivo ou pasta diretamente via SFTP o servidor permite sem problemas.

Toda vez que faço upload de uma pasta ou arquivo via Wordpress e preciso alterar posteriormente de forma manual a pasta ou arquivos via SFTP, preciso rodar o seguinte comando para o servidor não me retornar acesso negado:

```
sudo chown -R  usuario:www-data /var/www
```

Porque isso acontece? Configurei de forma incorreta as permissões? Quando eu utilizo o Wordpress pra fazer upload ele gera a pasta e arquivos com permissões diferentes?

Comment: O usuário do servidor web não é o mesmo do FTP, basicamente. Uma possibilidade seria trocar a permissão do diretório todo ou no momento do upload, para permitir um acesso mais amplo. Mas cuidado com hospedagem compartilhada, pois pode haver acesso indevido entre usuários.

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre pois o seu Apache é executado pelo usuário `www-data` e você está acessando o ftp por outro usuário. Assim, são usuários diferentes e um não tem permissão para alterar o arquivo do outro.

Você pode adicionar o seu usuário (usado no ftp) ao mesmo grupo do usuário `www-data` e deixar as permissões como 775 e 664 em vez de 755 e 664, como normalmente são. Isso permite escrita para o grupo todo.

Veja mais sobre chmod e permissões aqui: http://rberaldo.com.br/chmod-permissoes-em-sistemas-linux-e-unix-like/